# Identify the genre of a Mercedes trailer soundtrack

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

Today I watched the [trailer for the new Mercedes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7uGiiHsVr0). The video had a nice music playing on the background. It was kinda happy/mysterious style. I literally fell in love with the music.

I want to listen more to this kinda type songs. Can someone please tell me what genre this is, or what I have to type to search for this kinda music.

Comment: [Welcome to Music Fans Stack Exchange](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). Please clarify what have you tried. Here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you the **Gipsy Jazz Waltz** genre.

Here are some examples:

- [Montagne Sainte Genevieve from Django Reinhardt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bqP32YUZtE)
- [Oridano Gypsy Jazz Band - Oridano's Waltz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlPsg9-DFro)

Comment: In the comments on the Youtube post, in reply to one asking about the music, Mercedes reply "Thanks for your interest, but the song has been created especially for this video.".  so may be hard to get a name.....

Comment: @Angst I think OP didn't want to identify the song, but the genre.

Comment: Very true @Bebs, my error in reading too fast. I agree on your notion of the genre although the start could also be 19th c piano trio or similar but that is part of the gypsy jazz waltz style too...